# In jQuery Datatables, how we define fixed value columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

With `Jquery.datatables` i've build a data table which loads data from server dynamically by `Ajax` in `Json` format. this is my code:

```
$('#MyTable').dataTable({
  'sAjaxSource': '/Accounting/Action/GetData',
  'bStateSave': false,
  'bProcessing': true,
  'bServerSide': true,
  'data': {
  },
  'lengthChange': true,
  'aoColumns': [
    {
      'mData': 'ActionID',
      'title': 'کد',
      'sClass': ''
    },
    {
      'mData': 'ActionTitle',
      'title': 'عنوان',
      'sClass': ''
    }
  ],
  'sPaginationType': 'bootstrap'
});
```

it generates :

```
ActionID | ActionTitle  
=========+=============
  1      |  Foo         
---------+-------------
  2      |  Bar         
---------+-------------
  3      |  Blah Blah   
---------|------------
```

Ok, but i want to add a more column with fixed value for all rows and i don't do this by adding column to Json data which server sends. for example i want to add `MyFixedCol` to `MyGrid` in client side :

```
ActionID | ActionTitle | MyFixedCol
=========+=============+===========
  1      |  Foo        | FIXEDVAL
---------+-------------+-----------
  2      |  Bar        | FIXEDVAL
---------+-------------+-----------
  3      |  Blah Blah  | FIXEDVAL
---------|-------------+-----------
```

How can i do it?

Comment: https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/273

Answer (score 0):

I found a trick and it worked for me. so i share here, maybe help someone :)

`datatables` has a `createdRow` call back which fires it when row created. then i add a `<td>` to ther related row and it runs for all rows:

```
'createdRow': function ( row, data, index ) {
    $(row).append($('<td>').html('FIXEDVAL'));
  }
```

so my code in the question has been completed:

```
$('#MyTable').dataTable({
  'sAjaxSource': '/Accounting/Action/GetData',
  'bStateSave': false,
  'bProcessing': true,
  'bServerSide': true,
  'data': {
  },
  'lengthChange': true,
  'aoColumns': [
    {
      'mData': 'ActionID',
      'title': 'کد',
      'sClass': ''
    },
    {
      'mData': 'ActionTitle',
      'title': 'عنوان',
      'sClass': ''
    }
  ],
  'sPaginationType': 'bootstrap',
  'createdRow': function ( row, data, index ) {
       $(row).append($('<td>').html('FIXEDVAL'));
  }
});
```